# how to randomly select list items from a HTML file in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get 4 random list items from a html page named `songs.html`
which contains a format like:

```
<ul>
   <li value="1">..songname1..</li>
   <li value="2">..songname2..</li>
   <li value="3">...</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
var list = [];
$.get('songs.html', function(list){

});
```

Comment: what did you try till now (I mean other than an empty function)?

Comment: People here aren't going to write the code for you... that said, you should probably look at `Math.random()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Answer (score 0):

You can do that this way:

```
var list = [];
var numberToPick = 4;

$.get('songs.html', function(page){
    var elements = $(page).find('li').length,
        randomIndex;
    if (elements.length <= numberToPick)
        list = elements;
    else
        while(list.count < numberToPick) {
            randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * list.count));
            if ($.inArray(elements[randomIndex], list) == -1)
                list.push(elements[randomIndex]);
        }
});
```

This will iterate until it gets 4 different elements. If this condition is not necessary you can just loop it 4 times. If list is lower than expected number of elements it will return all of them.